# I don't understand why tickinterval and 'dot' on graph are not aligned?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle

I don't understand why tickinterval and 'dot' on graph are not aligned ?

We can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9vJT/2/), data of 'Feb 10' and tick interval of 'Feb 10' is not aligned.

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 0,
            plotBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            plotShadow: false,
            plotBorderWidth: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e. %b',
                week: '%e. %b',
                month: '%b \'%y',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            minorTickInterval: 1,
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'top',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
            navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Logins',
                data: [[1391407200000, 2],
                         [1391493600000, 2],
                         [1391580000000, 1],
                         [1392012000000, 1],
                         [1392098400000, 2],
                         [1392184800000, 1],
                         [1392271200000, 2],
                         [1392357600000, 1],
                         [1392616800000, 3],
                         [1392789600000, 1],
                         [1392876000000, 1],
                         [1393221600000, 2],
                         [1393308000000, 3],
                         [1393394400000, 1],
                         [1393480800000, 1]],
                pointInterval: 86400000,
                pointStart: 1391212800000
            }
          ]
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do the times match up with 00:00:00? If they do: are you sure the timezones match?

Comment: No I am not sure about timezones. How can I match timezones ?

Answer (score 2):

It is because the timestamp at tick on x-axis and the timestamp of the point are different

I've updated your fiddle so that the reason will be clear http://jsfiddle.net/F9vJT/4/

Comment: Yes I got your point but I don't understand why I am getting different timestamps in Javascript and Mysql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488144/getting-different-timestamp-in-mysql-and-javascript-for-the-same-date

Comment: I have update my mysql database timezone to UTC to fix this issue.