# Getting different timestamp in Mysql and Javascript for the same date?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, timezone

In Javascript

```
    new Date()
    Tue Mar 18 2014 18:54:17 GMT+0000 (GMT)
    Date.UTC(2014,03,18)
    1397779200000
```

In Mysql

```
mysql> SELECT  NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------+---------------------+
| NOW()               | UTC_TIMESTAMP()     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2014-03-18 18:55:04 | 2014-03-18 18:55:04 |
+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-18') ;
+------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-18') |
+------------------------------+
|                   1395118800 |
```

Comment: JS uses milliseconds, unix time stamps are in seconds. the rest of the difference is just the fact that you're running both bits of code at different times, e.g. March 18th 9:07am v.s. 9:08:31am or whatever. In practical terms, it's unlikely you'd EVER get the same timestamp from both, because JS and MySQl are completely different systems running in different places.

Comment: Can't I get the same UTC timestamp from both place for a specific date?

Comment: you are. but since you're not specifying the h/m/s for either timestamp, both system are pulling in the h/m/s for the current time when you run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three differences:

1. `Date.UTC()` interprets its arguments in UTC, whereas `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` interprets its arguments in the database session's timezone.  From the update to your question it appears that this may not have had any effect as the database session's local timezone might be in UTC.
2. `Date.UTC()` returns a value in milliseconds since the UNIX epoch, whereas `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns a value in seconds since the UNIX epoch: so they will always differ by a factor of 1000.
3. The month argument to `Date.UTC()` is zero-indexed, so a value of `03` indicates April whereas the date literal given to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` indicates March.

References are cited below.

### JavaScript

As documented under [`Date.UTC()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.3) (emphasis added):

> The `UTC` function differs from the `Date` constructor in two ways: it returns a [time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) as a Number, rather than creating a Date object, and **it interprets the arguments in UTC rather than as local time**.

Also, as documented under [`TimeClip()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.14) (emphasis added):

> The operator TimeClip calculates a **number of milliseconds** from its argument, which must be an ECMAScript Number value.

Also, as documented under [Month Number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.4):

> Months are identified by an integer in the range 0 to 11, inclusive.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> A month value of 0 specifies January; 1 specifies February; 2 specifies March; 3 specifies April; 4 specifies May; 5 specifies June; 6 specifies July; 7 specifies August; 8 specifies September; 9 specifies October; 10 specifies November; and 11 specifies December.

### MySQL

As documented under [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) (emphasis added):

> If [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as **seconds** since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC.  The server interprets ***`date`*** as a value **in the current time zone** and converts it to an internal value in UTC. Clients can set their time zone as described in [Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: @krunalshah: Also note that in JavaScript [months are indexed from zero](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.4), not one.  Thus, `Date.UTC(2014,03,18)` is actually 18th April 2014, not 18th March.

Comment: I have update my mysql database timezone to UTC to fix this issue.